# Como alinear en 1 linea las preguntas en Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Tengo 300 preguntas en Notepadd++

Tal que asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve ahí, en la captura, la pregunta 295 esta en 1 sola linea. Pero por ejemplo la 296 no.
Si se dan cuenta un detalle en color VERDE, cuando la pregunta esta en mas de una linea HAY UN ESPACIO VACIO. Se puede usar eso como condicion discriminante para juntar esa pregunta en 1 linea? Y asi con todas?

Agradezco de antemano, cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: y mi recomendacion sigue siendo la misma.. a mano, ya lo hubieras terminado.. no tenes un patron claro para saber en que caso o no, hay que sacar el salto de linea, porque no podes ubicar claramente la pregunta, ni saber donde termina la pregunta.. una expresion regular seria demasiado compleja y propensa a errores...

Comment: tengo en total 1800 preguntas.. dije 300 porque es 1 examen. A mano hice medio examen y tarde horas. Ya te subi le edicion de la pregunta.. fijate a ver si ahora con lo que note yo, podes sacar algo en conclusion.

Comment: Si, que es peor de lo que pensas.. no solo no hay patron... tenes el mismo problema en las respuestas ;) fijate la 290 C... yo no creo que notepad++ sea la solucion que necesitas...

Comment: aca, lo que necesitas es mas simple, pero no en notepad++.. agarras cualquier lenguaje, abris el archivo, y vas linea por linea, de forma tal que haya un ) en cada linea (y si no, pegas el texto) o un ANSWER... de paso, el programa ya te queda...

Comment: Y eso no es un espacio.. eso quiere decir que es la misma linea.. raro.. seguro que son lineas distintas?? seguro que hay un salto de linea?? podrias prender los saltos de linea y fijarte si realemnte hay uno?

Comment: espera dame tiempo que estoy asimilando me diste 40 directrices..

Comment: Lenguaje me estas hablando de lenguajes de programación? O lenguajes en Notepad++?

Si es lenguaje de programación como yo que sé, python, como abro un archivo?

Soy médico, no ingeniero de la NASA. Vine acá buscando algo sencillo.

Comment: Vas a tardar más tiempo tratando de buscar una expresión regular, ya que hay que contemplar casos como los que te dijeron más arriba (la pregunta 299: la opción C). No hay un patrón claro. Dedicate a seleccionar cada pregunta, y andá a _Editar_ > _Operaciones de limpieza_ > _Convertir los finales de línea en espacios_. Pareciera ser que eso es lo que estás buscando. Otra tarea: buscar cómo seleccionar "de una vez" todas esas preguntas.

Comment: creo que ninguno de nosotros es ingeniero de la nasa.. no lo se... la mayoria somos programadores (algunos mas expertos, otros menos)... mas alla de eso, no puedo ayudarte, porque por lo menos yo no veo un patron para dilucidar que es pregunta, que es respuesta, y donde hay que borrar los saltos de linea (que tampoco tengo claro que existan)... ojo, tal vez ni siquiera sea notepad++ la herramienta que necesitas...

Comment: Me ayudo un yankee en el foro de notepad++ la solucion era

Comment: Find: (?-s)^\d+\..+\K\R(?!A\))
Replace: a single space
Search mode: Regular expression

Comment: Y si.. es mas logico, porque alli saben usar la herramienta.. aca sabemos programar otras cosas ;) de igual forma, la respuesta va en el campo respuestas!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find: (?-s)^\d+..+\K\R(?!A))

Replace: a single space (esto significa que dejen un espacio en blanco, no que pongan el texto "a single space")

Search mode: Regular expression –

Solución.

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer]. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega detalles del porqué esto soluciona el problema. Explica lo que hace el patrón de expresión regular que has usado.

Comment: "A single space" probablemente es "un solo espacio" como tal. Así como lo escribiste, se entiende que vas a reemplazar los datos con ese texto tal cual. ¡Traducilo! y respondé en base a [answer].

Comment: Padaleiana.. mejor la respuesta imposible. Puse la solución. Si quieren hacer un cursito de Notepad++ adelante. Yo no tengo tiempo. Traducir si puedo hacerlo.

Comment: No se notifican los comentarios salvo que menciones a cada usuario en particular con un @. Y no hay que enojarse... Procuramos cuidar la calidad del sitio. Por otra parte, tu respuesta no necesariamente es la solución, sino es lo que te ha sido útil.

Comment: Y si creés que tu respuesta es efectivamente útil, considerá [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) (con el "check" a la izquierda de la respuesta).